# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined by creating a graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a directed graph with my Javascript code which I created. By clicking on a node, the list of publications assigned to a keyword should be called up. The currently selected node should be highlighted in the visualisation. The details should be shown on a separate grey area which i created:

```
  <div id="detail_box"></div>
```

For each publication, there should be the first name, last name and date of birth. In addition, the name of the selected keyword should also appear in the grey area. The selection changes by clicking on another node. Here is a example what i want to do: My Javascript (persona.json):

```
    "KayO": {
      firstname: "Kay",
      lastname: "Ohran",
      Birthdate: "11.09.64",
      Hobby: "footbal",
      City: "California",
      skills: "java, python, HTML, json, oculus rift,",
    },...
```

If i click on these node: it should show these data in my "detailed box":

```
KayO
first name: Kay
last name: Ohran
date of birth: 11.09.64
```

How can i make this? I have tried it, but unfortunately im getting a Error Message:

```
index.html:147 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (index.html:147)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3.v6.js:2107)
```

Here is my code -> I'm using D3.js V6:

```
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
  <script src="persona.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that `persona[keyName]` is undefined. We are not given declaration of `persona` array to make better research.

Comment: thx. I have adjusted my code (also edited above). But unfortunately I get something wrong. Instead of outputting the first name, last name and date of birth, it only outputs the entire keyword. This is what it outputs when I click on a node: `KayO;Benbeck;Borea;...`. Only when I click on these one text the data appear. How can I change this?

Comment: Do you still get the error? Also, try to print entire `persona` array to ensure that everything is correct inside.